# How can I get month from current system date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get only month from current system date.I tried something like below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `audit` JOIN `user` ON `user`.id=`audit`.`auditor_id` WHERE  `audit`.`auditor_id`=1 AND MONTH(`audit`.`created_date`)=NOW()
```

But, not getting any count from this query. can I make query like this using NOW()?

Comment: What about the year? Aren't there rows of the previous year's current month in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing the logic like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `audit` a JOIN
     `user` u
     ON u.id = a.auditor_id
WHERE a.auditor_id = 1 AND 
      a.created_date >= curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate()) day AND
      a.created_date < (curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate()) day) + interval 1 month;
```

This has two advantages over using `MONTH(a.created_date)`.  First, it includes the year, so only the current month is considered.

Perhaps more importantly, this is "index-safe".  It can make use of an index on `audit(auditor_id, created_date)`.  To optimize index usage you want to avoid functions on columns.

Answer (score 2):

Use `month()` function

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `audit` JOIN `user` ON `user`.id=`audit`.`auditor_id` 
WHERE  `audit`.`auditor_id`=1 AND MONTH(`audit`.`created_date`)=month(NOW())
```

Comment: yeah this what I was thinking while posting this question. anyways thank you